# Visitor with type parameter acting upon types not from the specified type parameter

Tags: java, generics, factory, visitor-pattern

I am using a generic abstract class of a framework `AbstractProcessor<T extends CtElement>` which is basically a visitor that visits all elements T. There is a method

```
public void process(T element)
```

that acts upon all elements of the specified type and does something.

I then have implemented another abstract class myself which adds a couple of features to this class of the framework `GenerationProcessor<T extends CtElement> extends AbstractProcessor<T>`.

Then there are concrete class implementations of `GenerationProcessor` that I create using some sort of factory pattern, while holding a list of type `GenerationProcessor` to then call the `process`-method via polymorphism. One of these might be `XYZProcessor<T extends CtElement> extends GenerationProcessor<T>`. When I now create these concrete processors and try to give them a concrete Type (that extends CtElement of course) so the visitor-pattern visits on these elements like this `new XYZProcessor<CtNamedElement>()` where `CtNamedElement` is a subtype of `CtElement`, I do not get the intended output. The `process`-method seems to get called for all visisted elements of type `CtElement`, NOT only for those of the type `CtNamedElement` as I want to (since the constructor call for the XYZProcessor with the type param CtNamedElement).

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: Please show the `CtNamedElement` class (at least the first line of the class). My gues is it's typed, so your code should be should thing like `new XYZProcessor<CtNamedElement<Foo>>()`

Comment: It's better to show code than to describe it. You probably declared `CtNamedElement` with some type parameter. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: CtNamedElement is indeed declared with a type parameter itself, thats why the warning occurs. It seems like my real problem then is the question why my visitor acts upon all CtElement-types and not only on these of type CtNamedElement. Looks like the visit()-method that gets called on the super-class GenerationProcessor via polymorphism does not know the type the concrete processor got instantiated with or so.

Comment: I should probably post another question for this, but thanks.